# Equal heights on 4 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to modify my JS to only affect 4 items at a time. I'd like for it to find the 1st 4 instances of .prodbox, then based on the height of those 4 instances, normalize them. Then, do the next 4 instances of .prodbox, and normalize them. So on and so forth.

So essentially, I have "Product Boxes" (.prodbox) on a line with 4 products on each line. I'd like to make them nice & uniform with this JS. But I only want it to effect 1 line at a time so each line is inline with itself.

This is so products with large product names, but are on the same line with products that have small product names, can look decently aligned.

For instance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvPJJ.png  The suncast heavy duty storage box is a 2 line name product. To make everything look "in line" the height of the other products is adjusted even though they do not have 2 lines of product name.

My JS code is;

```
$(window).bind('load',function(){
    var largestHeight=0;
    $('.prodbox').each(function(){
        var prodbox=$(this);
        var prodboxHeight=prodbox.height();
        if(prodboxHeight>largestHeight){
            largestHeight=prodboxHeight}
        });
$('.prodbox').height(largestHeight)});
```

Comment: Could you define normalize?  Do these boxes contain content?  What if the content does not fit within the normalized boxes?

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot or something to help me understand more.  I think I understand what you are going for, but I am not 100%. Some HTML would help too.

Comment: please also show your markup with the prodbox(s) or even better create a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have edited my text above with a screenshot. I am using the code now, but it looks at all instances of .prodbox, and affects all instances of .prodbox on the page at a time. I want it to look at per line of products (4).

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle. I'm using 2 sections. 1 section is Featured Items, the 2nd is New Items. Should be viewed at 1200px+ so I recommend expanding the Result window quite a lot to see what I'm talking about. Please note the JS external resources I am using.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnn3H/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/5dJ2S/)

```
$(".prodbox").each(function(i){
    i++;
    $rowNumber = (Math.ceil(i/4) - 1)*4;
    $maxHeight = Math.max(
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber).height(),
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+1).height(),
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+2).height(),
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+3).height()
        );
    $(this).height($maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this but on my 2nd line I'm seeing this:
http://i.imgur.com/cLJSKVi.png

Essentially, the product with the most height in its' name is being blocked off by the pricing area.

Comment: Your first `.prodbox` has an inline style of `height:40px`. Remove this as this is overriding the dynamic height. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzWm2/)

Comment: Actually, remove any and all inline style in your `.prodbox` divs.

Comment: Yeah, after looking I have literally no inline styles on my .prodboxes. Are those being added from the JS?

Comment: Also, the code in my CMS looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/Dpoate0.png  So yeah, no inlines here as far as I can see.

Comment: The inline are in your original fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hnn3H/.

Not sure how they got there. There were too many errors so I had to remove all but the jQuery files to update my demo.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML looks something like this, with each row of `.prodbox` elements inside a container (I gave it class `line` here):

```
<div class="line">
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
     <div class="prodbox"></div>
</div>
```

Then you could loop through the `line` elements and use JQuery's `find` method to get all `.prodbox` elements within each line.  The javascript might look like this (not tested):

```
$(window).bind('load',function(){
    var largestHeight=0;
    $('.line').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.prodbox').each(function() {
            var prodbox=$(this);
            var prodboxHeight=prodbox.height();
            if(prodboxHeight>largestHeight){
                largestHeight=prodboxHeight}
            });
        $('.prodbox').height(largestHeight)});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to wrap each row in a div with a "row" class. Then you could iterate through each row, and use your own code.

```
$(window).bind('load',function(){
    $('.row').each(function () {
        var largestHeight=0;
        $(this).children('.prodbox').each(function(){
            var prodbox=$(this);
            var prodboxHeight=prodbox.height();
            if(prodboxHeight>largestHeight) {
                largestHeight=prodboxHeight
            }
        });
        $(this).children('.prodbox').height(largestHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle. I'm using 2 sections. 1 section is Featured Items, the 2nd is New Items. Should be viewed at 1200px+ so I recommend expanding the Result window quite a lot to see what I'm talking about. Please note the JS external resources I am using. jsfiddle.net/hnn3H